# How to sum time format (hh:mm:ss.ms) in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sum, date-arithmetic

I'm trying add time in mysql which is having format (hh:mm:ss.ms) but after addition millisecond value is getting 00

what i tried is

```
SEC_TO_TIME(sum(time_to_sec(TIMEDURATION)))
```

as i got to know it is converting time into seconds not getting anything for milisecond. my time format is something like this 19:30:10.903

Comment: what is desired output

Comment: Please read the guidelines in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly. Also, [For the 1024 time – DateTime has no format!](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Comment: @Oyeme this wont work for milisecond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, `time_to_sec()` loses the fractional seconds. On the other hand, `sec_to_time()` is capable of properly handling fractional seconds.

One solution is to sum the fractional seconds separately, like, then add them back before converting back to a time:

```
sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(timeduration)) + sum(microseconds(timeduration)) / 1000000)
```

Comment: Now all we need is a comment by BGM and we'll complete a full circle :-)

Comment: @GMB i'm getting invalid use of group function error

Comment: @ZoharPeled: ah ah... how about https://stackoverflow.com/users/277450/bgm?

Comment: @MBG: there was a missing parenthese in the expression, I just fixed that.